# Dropout with permutation in Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, permutation, dropout

According to Pytorch's documentation on [Dropout1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.dropout1d.html)

> Randomly zero out entire channels (a channel is a 1D feature map, e.g., the j-th channel of the i-th sample in the batched input is a 1D tensor input `[i, j]`). Each channel will be zeroed out independently on every forward call with probability p using samples from a Bernoulli distribution.

Then does that mean, with a tensor of shape `(batch, channel, time)`, `permute(0, 2, 1)` should be used along with `F.dropout1d()`, so that the dropout will affect the `channel` dimension?

```
    x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)   # convert to [batch, channels, time]
    x = F.dropout1d(x, p)
    x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)   # back to [batch, time, channels]
```

And will this piece of code be equivalent to Tensorflow's `SpatialDropout1D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, this piece of code will zero out values along the `channel` dimension, and scale the remaining outputs by inputs by `1/(1-p)` so the sum over all inputs remains unchanged on average. That corresponds to the exact same behavior as tensorflow's `SpatialDropout1D`.

A code snippet to compare what the outputs look like:

```py
x = np.array([[[1, 0, 1], [2, 8.2, 2]]])

xtf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
xtf = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(xtf, training=True)
print(xtf)

xp = torch.from_numpy(x)
xp = xp.permute(0, 2, 1)  
xp = torch.nn.functional.dropout1d(xp, 0.2)
xp = xp.permute(0, 2, 1)
print(xp)
```

Comment: Thank you! Are there any choices in Pytorch that will provide a result the same as `SpatialDropout1D`?

Comment: It seems that I was mistaken, pytorch's `dropout1d` does also scale the outputs, thought that behavior is not mentioned in the documentation. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I did some research, and it seems that Pytorch's `dropout1d` applies the dropout probability `p` to every single elements, while Tensorflow's `SpatialDropout1D` applies to an axis, i.e. a whole feature map.

Comment: `dropout1d` does apply the zeroing per channel as specified [in the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout1d.html#torch.nn.Dropout1d) and as you can check for yourself by running the snippet provided in the answer.